# How to Route without reloading the whole page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am Using react-route, and i am facing some trouble with routing.

The whole page is reloading , causing all the data that i have already fetched and stored in the reducer to load every time.

Here is my Route file :

```
var CustomRoute = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                <IndexRedirect to="/landing" />
                <Route path="landing" component={Landing} />
                <Route path="login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="form" component={Form} />
                <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    },
});
```

Before routing i already store data by calling action in my main.jsx

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
'use strict'
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
var React = require('react')
var Index = require('./components/index')
var createStore = require("redux").createStore
var applyMiddleware = require("redux").applyMiddleware
var Provider = require("react-redux").Provider
var thunkMiddleware = require("redux-thunk").default
var reducer = require("./reducers")
var injectTapEventPlugin =require('react-tap-event-plugin');
injectTapEventPlugin()
var createStoreWithMiddleware=applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);
var store=createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
store.dispatch(actions.load_contacts()) //////////// <<<<<< this is what i call to store data already

ReactDOM.render( <Provider store={store}><Index/></Provider> , document.getElementById('content'))
```

The issue is i have to route to another page if sucess login :

```
this.props.dispatch(actions.login(this.state.login,this.state.password,(err)=>{
    this.setState({err:err})
    if (!err){
        window.location = "/form"
    }
}));
```

The **window.location** does the trick but it reloads everything which is very inefficient. 
In manual route i use `<Link\>` that routes without reloading, however for automated i am not sure how to do it.

Any Suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

for the most recent release (`v2.0.0-rc5`), the recommended navigation method is by directly pushing onto the history singleton.

[DEMO](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

**Relevant code**

```
import { browserHistory } from './react-router'
browserHistory.push('/some/path')
```

If using the newer react-router API, you need to make use of the `history` from `this.props` when inside of components so:

```
static propTypes = {
    history: React.PropTypes.object
}

this.props.history.push('/some/path');
```

If using `react-router-redux`, it offers a `push` function you can dispatch like so:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
this.props.dispatch(push('/some/path'));
```

In **v2.4.0** and above, use a higher order component to get the router as a prop of your component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Example extends React.Component {
   // use `this.props.router.push('/some/path')` here
};

// Export the decorated class
var DecoratedExample = withRouter(Example);

// PropTypes

Example.propTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.shape({
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};
```

Visit this link for more information: http://kechengpuzi.com/q/s31079081

Comment: Thanks at lot , this did the trick for me .
Just import `var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory` 
and call `browserHistory.push('/form')` .

Comment: I did this and the entire page is still refreshing

Comment: DEMO example link is down (404). More information link is also unavailable. Can you update this answer?

Answer (score 15):

**React >= 16.8 and react-router v4**

No one mentioned a solution for an app using hooks. Since React 16.8 (and react-router 4, not sure what is the minimal version, I use the latest), you can use a hook called useHistory.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

const MyHookComponent: React.FC = () => {
    
    const routerHistory = useHistory();
    routerHistory.push('/page-where-to-redirect');

    return <></>;
}

export default MyHookComponent;
```

More info here https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/.

**Update: react-router v6**

There was a new hook introduced in react-router 6:

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/page-where-to-redirect');
```

Documentation can be be found here https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Comment: ```navigate('/page-where-to-redirect');``` not working in case of same page redirect.

Comment: To refresh the current page, `navigate(0)` should work.

Answer (score 12):

This is the only thing that worked for me:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", "/new-url");
```

OR to replace:

```
window.history.replaceState("", "", "/new-url");
```

Answer (score 4):

Import th Link component first :

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

instead of :

```
<Route path="landing" component={Landing} />
```

use :

```
<Link to="landing" />
```

Comment: Then how should React-Bootstrap know to show the `Landing` page if it is not even stated? Link to "/landing" or anything similar is meaningless without the `Route` component..

Answer (score 1):

Following is the sample routes configuration that I have used in some of my projects and it should be helpful to you:

```
import App from '../App';
import Home from '../components/pages/Home';
import Login from '../components/pages/Login';
import Register from '../components/pages/Register';

function shouldBeLoggedIn(nextState, replace) {
  // const status = getLoginStatus(); //From the State manager
  // if( status && !status.loggedin ){
  //   replace({
  //     pathname: '/login',
  //     state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
  //   })
  // }
  console.log('Should be Logged in!')
}

function shouldNotBeLoggedIn(nextState, replace) {
  // const status = getLoginStatus();
  // if( status && status.loggedin ){
  //   replace({
  //     pathname: '/home',
  //     state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
  //   })
  // }
  console.log('Should Not be Logged in!')
}

const rootRoute = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: {
    component: Login,
    onEnter: shouldNotBeLoggedIn
  },
  indexRedirect: {
    to: '/'
  },
  childRoutes: [ {
      path: 'home',
      component: Home,
      onEnter: shouldBeLoggedIn
    }, {
      path: 'login',
      component: Login,
      onEnter: shouldNotBeLoggedIn
    }, {
      path: 'register',
      component: Register,
      onEnter: shouldNotBeLoggedIn
    }
  ]
}

export default rootRoute;
```

In above code, each route has a onEnter hook to the router's lifecycle methods which will decide that whether the route should be entered or not. And if you look at the comment, you can decide what to do in the hooked method.

You can browse above code at following github repo: http://github.com/pankajpatel/kickstart-react and the file at https://github.com/pankajpatel/kickstart-react/blob/master/src/js/routes/routes.js

Following is the example from the [react-router's API documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback):

```
const userIsInATeam = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
  fetch(...)
    .then(response = response.json())
    .then(userTeams => {
      if (userTeams.length === 0) {
        replace(`/users/${nextState.params.userId}/teams/new`)
      }
      callback();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // do some error handling here
      callback(error);
    })
}

<Route path="/users/:userId/teams" onEnter={userIsInATeam} />
```

Answer (score 1):

**React Router v4 - Redirect Component**

The react-router v4 recommended way is to allow your render method to catch a redirect. Use state or props to determine if the redirect component needs to be shown.

Reference : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

1. Import the `Redirect` from `react-router`.

   ```
   import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
   ```
2. Define the Click event to change the state.

   ```
   handleOnClick = () => {
       // redirect
       this.setState({redirect: true});
   }
   ```
3. Change Render method like,

   ```
   render() {
       if (this.state.redirect) {
       return <Redirect push to="/yourpath" />;
       }

       return ( <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} type="button">Button</button> );
   }
   ```

   - Example code :

     ```
     import { Redirect } from 'react-router'; //import Redirect 

     export default class ConfirmationDialog extends Component{

         constructor(props)
         {
             super(props);
             //init the state
             this.state = {
                 redirect : false
             }
         }

         handleOnClick = () => {
             //set the redirect property to true for allow redirect
             this.setState({redirect: true});
         }

         render() {
              //check if the redirec is allowed
              if (this.state.redirect) {
                   return <Redirect push to="/yourpath" />;
              }
              //if not put your code here
               return (
                       //your code
                       <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} 
                              type="button">Button</button>
               );

         }
     }
     ```